# serverside javascript and multiple keys in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I am having problems with updating a row in a data extension (DE).
Usually my DE only has one primary key. In this case there are three.
When I have it like the code below, all rows that has the same country_code are updated.

But I just want to update rows where country_code AND program AND e_number match.
How should I write that final row to make it happen?

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core","1");

var e_number = Request.GetFormField("e_number");

requestsDE.Rows.Update({
e_subline: 'bla bla bla'
},
["country_code"], [countrycode], ["program"], [program],["e_number"], [e_number]
);
</script>
```

The field in the DE is numeric. However I guess "e_number" that I receive from a form is a string. Might that also be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there - you need to combine all the columns and values into a single array, not multiple arrays like in your example. Likely it was only filtering on the first 2 arrays (name | value) and ignoring the rest as they are not included in the function properties.

See below:

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core","1");

var e_number = Request.GetFormField("e_number");

requestsDE.Rows.Update({
e_subline: 'bla bla bla'
},
["country_code", "program", "e_number"], [countrycode, program, e_number]
);
</script>
```